# I want to add 4 different conditions in html select box

Tags: html

Here is my html code:

```
<select name="field">
    <option value="Camera">Camera</option>
    <option value="Clothing">Clothing</option>
    <option value="Coins">Coins</option>
    <option value="Mobile">Mobiles</option>
</select>
```

Now i want "if i select Camera then i will redirect to another page may be camera.html page. Similarly if i select Clothing then i will redirect to another page may be clothing.html page in the same way for other 2 options as well i want same functionality.

It will be easy for me if ill use 4 different links for these using  tag but i want this done using a Submit button of the form. I want to do this thing with select box and on-submit call rather then 4 different links..

So i badly need help regarding this.. Please help me and explain me this with code so i can understand how can i achieve this??

Comment: With HTML you can't, but you can with JavaScript. Are you able to use JavaScript in your project?

Comment: A drop-down menu would probably achieve better functionality than a native form field.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a JavaScript handler like this:

```
<select onchange="location.href=this.value+'.html'">
```

If you want to do this with a submit button you need to add some more code:

```
<form onsubmit="location.href=this.form.target.value; return false;">
  <select name="target">...</select>
  <input type="submit" />
  ...
```

Comment: I can use Javascript if someone can teach me a bit how can i do this using Javascript. And  i want this done using a Submit button of the form. I want to do this thing with select box. On-submit it will check if Camera has been selected then it will go to its page and similarly others .. I don't want to use any drop down menu for this. As i also have other text fields in this form of select box

Comment: I am not getting your code exactly where should i add the 4 links for all 4 choices ??

Comment: I just omitted the options from your question. Basically I prevent that the form is submitted and I redirect the user to the page which you have defined in the value attributes of the option tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to depend on JavaScript for this, just make the form pass the data via GET. This way, you can access the selected option in .htaccess. Through a RewriteCond, you could rewrite the action to the desired page:

```
<form method="get" action="nonexistent.html">
    <select name="gotofile">
        <option value="camera">Camera</option>
        <option value="clothing">Clothing</option>
        <option value="coins">Coins</option>
        <option value="mobile">Mobiles</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

In the .htaccess-File:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^gotofile=([^&]+) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &gotofile=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^nonexistens\.html$ %1.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the 'value' attribute to point to the URL / web page that you want to go to and then use JavaScript (or jQuery) to redirect the user.

E.g.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function redirect() {

            var myUrl = document.getElementById("selectBox").value;
            window.location.href = myUrl;

            return false;

        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form onSubmit="return redirect()">
        <select id="selectBox" name="field">
            <option value="Camera.html">Camera</option>
            <option value="Clothing.html">Clothing</option>
            <option value="Coins.html">Coins</option>
            <option value="Mobile.html">Mobiles</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** I have updated my code to use onSubmit() as you asked.

Comment: Should it work for onSubmit button call of the form ??? Like i call it within submit button as onSubmit="redirect()"

Comment: Can you help me on that too please ??                              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686196/i-want-to-save-the-data-from-text-fields-and-select-boxes-of-html-and-want-to-pa

Comment: Yes yar Anas you can use the function on onSubmit as well.

Comment: @MUHAMMADANASANJUMAGHA I have updated the code as per your requirement so that now it uses onSubmit.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, you want the select item to be links.  if this is indeed what you are asking then a simple

```
<option><a href=`yoursite.html`>something</a></option>
```

Should work

Comment: No thats not i am asking i want that if any of choice is selected form select box then there is a Submit button in the form so when anyone click on Submit button it will go to that particular page depending upon the choice of option in select box

Answer (score 0):

Really nice and easy to do this with jQuery. The jQuery library is located for download at http://jquery.com/download/.

I suggest adding the names of the pages as the vales or naming your pages so that the values are contained in the name of the page (ie if the page name was cameraPage.html have the value of the camera option be "cameraPage" or "cameraPage.html. The example below will use cameraPage, but you can change it how you please).

```
$("formName").submit(function(){
   window.location.href = $('option:selected').val()+".html";
});
```

The **$("formName")** selected selects your form and **.submit(function()** means you are now doing a function when the form is submitted.

**"window.location.href ="** redirects a user to what ever comes after the =.

**$('option:selected').val()** gets the value of the selected option.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this with PHP and a javscript redirect.
Here is the html for the form:

```
<form action="yourscript.php" method="post">
   <select name="field">
      <option value="Camera">Camera</option>
      <option value="Clothing">Clothing</option>
      <option value="Coins">Coins</option>
      <option value="Mobile">Mobiles</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And here is the php in yourscript.php:

```
<?PHP
$field = $_POST['field'];
if ($field == "Camera"){
   ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   window.location.href='cameras.php';
   </script>
   <?PHP
}
else if ($field == "Clothing"){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href='clothing.php';
    </script>
    <?PHP
}
else if ($field == "Coins"){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href='coins.php';
    </script>
    <?PHP
}
else if ($field == "Mobile"){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href='mobile.php';
    </script>
    <?PHP
}
?>
```